# Returning true/false value to bash from node script

Tags: node.js, bash

Is it possible to get a true/false value from a node script which also writes something into std output?

```
// node script
console.log('doing something');
if (doSomething()) {
  return true; // I would like to get this in bash
}

return false; // Or this
```

Then in my bash I read it like this

```
SUCCESS=$(node script.js)
```

but the problem is that `SUCCESS` contains all the logging from `console.log` but not the return value.

In my environment, I can't use exit codes for this, otherwise the whole script fails.

Comment: You can't access a return value like that. Either output it (e.g. by writing it to STDOUT) , write it to a file or use exit codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a two main options for this I can see:

1. Return a status code, and use it carefully to ensure it doesn't crash your script, e.g:

   ```
   SUCCESS=$((node script.js && echo 'ok') || echo 'fail')
   ```

   This line always returns successfully, even if node returns a non-zero exit code. After this runs, `SUCCESS` will be set to either `ok` or `fail`, depending on the result - you can replace that with whatever logic you'd prefer.
2. Print output as the last line from your comand, and use `node script.js | tail -n1` to collect only the last line of the output, and ignore the rest of the logging

I would recommend 1 if you can, but if you really need to avoid using status codes, or you need more complex output, you may want to go for option 2.